# How can I copy the contents of a folder to another folder in a different directory using terminal?

Tags: command-line, cp

I am trying to copy the contents of a folder to another folder in a different directory using terminal.

Would somebody be able to provide me an example of the command line syntax required to achieve this?

Comment: Ciao @pandisvezia! Serviva anche a me questa cosa!

Answer (score 1961):

You can copy the content of a folder `/source` to another existing folder `/dest` with the command

```
cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

The `-a` option is an improved recursive option, that preserve all file attributes, and also preserve symlinks.

The `.` at end of the source path is a specific `cp` syntax that allow to copy all files and folders, included hidden ones.

Comment: @enzotib I am trying to use this command to copy the contents of "Downloads/textext" to "~/.config/inkscape/extensions/." Using your command I type "cp -a /Downloads/textext/. /~/.config/inkscape/extensions/." but this does not work

Comment: @Funzies: probably your command should be: `cp -a ~/Downloads/textext/. ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/`

Comment: Add `-p` flag as to preserve the file permissions and timestamps. `cp -ap /var/www/original.com/images/. /var/www/new.com/images/`

Comment: @DylanValade: `-a` already implies `--preserve=all`, that is wider than `-p = --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`.

Comment: Note: If you directory name contains spaces, then you need to quote the arguments like `cp -a /media/ubuntu/Volume/. '/media/ubuntu/My Passport/'`. And if you want to encrypt your files, then you can use the `scp` (Secure Copy) command.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer: `scp` is used to copy over a network (through `ssh`) and only encrypts the communication channel, not the files on the destination filesystem.

Comment: @PawelCioch: `cp -r` is recursive copy, `-a` add some other option, like `--preserve=all`

Comment: I'd suggest prepending the folder paths in the answer with `.` so the command will work in the local directory, just not to confuse the begginers

Comment: Such a great answer! The `-a` option even set up git in my destination directory.

Comment: What I like about -a is that it preserves symlinks. What I don't like is that it copies recursively (including the sub-folders, which is not what cp usually does). How can I preserve symlinks without copying sub-folders recursively?

Comment: @user1271772: to preserve symlinks without recursing directories you need `cp -d`, you may also add `--preserve=all`

Comment: The `mv` command does not list the -a flag. Could the `cp` move files instead of copying them with another flag?

Comment: One cannot always presume `rsync` is installed, so it is important to know how to achieve similar with GNU `cp`. Thanks.

Comment: "The . at end of the source path is a specific cp syntax that allow to copy all files and folders, included hidden ones.", this is not related to cp, but related to bash. The dot means "this location" and avoids the use of bash globbing, where by default files/directories starting with a . are not expanded.

Comment: @BrunoPereira: my sentence is wrong, but I think `bash` has nothing to do with this. It is UNIX that indicates the current directory with a dot, and `cp`, when given two directories `path/foo` and `bar` as arguments and a recursive option, like `-a`, creates a new directory `foo` under `bar` and copies all files contained in `path/foo` under `bar/foo`. If `bar/foo` already exists, the creation step is skipped. This is what happens here, given that `dest/.` already exists.

Comment: I would suggest `yes | cp -a /source/. /dest/` to accept the replacing

Comment: @enzotib Following up on Bruno Pereira's thread, could you edit your answer to remove the part about "specific cp syntax"? I think it's a bit misleading. Otherwise, it's a great answer.

Comment: this gives me `/dest/source/` i just want the contents of `/source/` not the folder itself :(

Comment: I think it should be noted that if the destination folder already exists, it and its contents might be overwritten by cp. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275969/does-cp-a-refresh-existing-files-overwrite-or-skip)

Comment: I want to copy a fonts files from a source software to .fonts in home, and for my working: cp -a fonts/. ~/.fonts/Shutter-Encoder

Comment: Can someone explain the need behind use of `mypath/.` instead of the existing bash wildcard expansion character, `mypath/*`?

Comment: @Elysiumplain: you missed the "included hidden files" part

Answer (score 199):

An alternate is `rsync`:

```
rsync -a source/ destination
```

The advantages of `rsync` are:

1. After the initial sync, it will then copy only the files that have changed.
2. You can use it over a network, convenient for files in $HOME, especially config files.

Comment: I think you don't need the asterisk. `rsync -r source/ destination` should be enough, no?

Comment: This one is more appropriate: 'rsync -rtvp source/* destination'

Comment: -r not works for hidden files/folders

Comment: This will not copy hidden files, since bash expands * only to non-hidden file. The solution by @Joschua is safer.

Comment: rsync will copy the entire directory, including hidden files, if you use the trailing / without a * so `rync source/ dest` Obviously people will need to customize the rsync command to function as they wish.

Comment: I rather the verbose and all option: `rsync -av source/ destination`

Comment: You can use the `--delete` flag to delete files from `destination` that aren't in `source`

Comment: Is the rsync command faster than CP? IT is doing like one 10 KB text file per 10 seconds.

Comment: I dont know , but it will only transfer new or changed files so will be simple to script

Comment: If it's a big folder you may wish to use one of these options to view progress while it's copying https://askubuntu.com/questions/609303/how-can-i-view-a-progress-bar-when-running-rsync

Comment: What if in source directory i will remove something after init sync, and run again sync? It will be removed also in destination, or only new things will be copied?

Comment: The OP asks "copy the **contents** of a folder to another folder". Removing the asterisk means we now copy the folder itself, which **isn't the right answer** when we wish to retain the target (e.g. because it's a drive or has existing content).

Answer (score 129):

Lets say you have a folder called *folder1* in your `~`, inside *folder1* is 1 file called *file1* and 2 folders called *sub1* and *sub2* each with other files and folders inside them.

To copy all the contents of `~/folder1` to `~/new_folder1` you would use

```
cp -r ~/folder1/. ~/new_folder1
```

`new_folder1` would then contain all the files and folders from `folder1`.

`cp` is the command to copy using a terminal, `-r` makes it recursively (so, current directory + further directories inside current) `~/folder1` is the origin folder, `~/new_folder1` is the destination folder for the files/folders inside the origin.

Comment: it does not catch hidden files

Comment: Thank you Bruno! It helped me to understand the syntax, though I had to change it a bit(removing ~ sign). Maybe because the destination folder was in /opt, which resides in another file system. And thank you Portablejim to remember the hidden file thing!

Comment: The trailing period is important. Without it, sometimes it may create a new subdirectory `~/new_folder1/folder1` instead of copying the contents over.

Comment: Why not `cp -r ~/folder1/* ~/new_folder1`

Comment: @Alex78191 `[root@ home]# mkdir food
[root@ home]# cd food/
[root@ food]# mkdir .fruit
[root@ food]# mkdir veggies
[root@ food]# touch veggies/carrots
[root@ food]# touch .fruit/apple
[root@ food]# ls *
carrots
[root@ food]#`

Comment: @Alex78191 Why do we use * vs . ?

> cp -a /source/. /dest/
vs.
> cp -r ~/source/* ~/dest/

Comment: @HeggyHere why?

Comment: I'm still getting `~/folder1/new_folder1/`, period doesn't seem to have an effect? Which version of bash does this work for?

Answer (score 51):

### Simple example.

Copy the ***directory dir_1 and its contents (*files*)*** into directory ***dir_2***:

```
cp -r ./dir_1 ./dir_2
# or
cp -r ./dir_1/ ./dir_2/
# Results in: ./dir_2/dir_1/_files_
```

Copy ***only the contents (*files*) of dir_1*** into directory ***dir_2***:

```
cp -r ./dir_1/. ./dir_2
# or
cp -r ./dir_1/. ./dir_2/
# Results in: ./dir_2/_files_
```

`_files_` is a placeholder for the actual files located in the directory.

Answer (score 25):

Check this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/copy-folder-linux-command-line/ for more information on copying folder.  Hope this helps.

```
cp Command
```

`cp` is a Linux command for copying files and directories. The syntax is as follows:

```
cp source destination
cp dir1 dir2
cp -option  source destination
cp -option1 -option2  source destination
```

In this example copy `/home/vivek/letters` folder and all its files to `/usb/backup` directory:

```
cp -avr /home/vivek/letters /usb/backup
```

Where,

`-a` : Preserve the specified attributes such as directory an file mode, ownership, timestamps, if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all.

`-v` : Explain what is being done.

`-r` : Copy directories recursively.
Example

Copy a folder called /tmp/conf to /tmp/backup:

```
$ cp -avr /tmp/conf/ /tmp/backup
```

Comment: This isn't what the question asks.

Comment: (Using -r with -a is redundant; on gnu cp -a is the same as "-dr --preserve=all")

Comment: **cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together.**

Answer (score 6):

This code with **Flag "-R"** copies **perfectly all the contents** of **"folder1"** to existing **"folder2"**:

```js
cp -R folder1/. folder2
```

**Flag "-R"** copies **symbolic links** as well but **Flag "-r"** skips **symbolic links** so **Flag "-R"** is better than **Flag "-r"**.

- **The latest GNU Grep 3.7**:

```
-R, --dereference-recursive

For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, 
recursively, following all symbolic links.
```

```
-r, --recursive

For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, 
recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command line, but skip symlinks 
that are encountered recursively. Note that if no file operand is given, 
grep searches the working directory. This is the same as the 
‘--directories=recurse’ option.
```

Answer (score 5):

I like this command

```
rsync -av --progress ~/code/project-source/. ~/code/project-destination --exclude .git --exclude node_modules
```

> Some of the commonly used options in rsync command are listed below:

- -v, –verbose: Verbose output
- -q, –quiet: suppress message output
- -a, –archive: archive files and directory while synchronizing ( -an equal to following options -rlptgoD)
- -r, –recursive: sync files and directories recursively
- -b, –backup: take the backup during synchronization
- -u, –update: don’t copy the files from source to destination if destination files are newer
- -l, –links: copy symlinks as symlinks during the sync
- -n, –dry-run: perform a trial run without synchronization
- -e, –rsh=COMMAND: mention the remote shell to use in rsync
- -z, –compress: compress file data during the transfer
- -h, –human-readable: display the output numbers in a human-readable format
- –progress: show the sync progress during transfer

Answer (score 3):

If there are two folders: (with write permission)

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 vimal vimal  4096 Sep  9 12:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root   4096 Aug 18 14:35 ..
drwxrwxrwx 6 vimal vimal  4096 Sep  9 12:15 DATA
drwxrwxrwx 7 vimal vimal  4096 Sep  9 12:15 PORTAL
```

If you are inside the folder called PORTAL where you want to copy all content of another folder say DATA at the same level
then you will do

`vimal@vimal-D3H:/var/www/html/PORTAL$ cp -a ../DATA/. .`

You have to notice 2 dots. Last dot says copy here in present folder

and

one following /DATA/. says that all the CONTENTS inside DATA folder to be copied, and not the DATA folder itself.

If you remove this trailing "." from /DATA/

then whole DATA folder will be copied inside PORTAL(from where you are coping).