# Manipulating a continuously changing command output stream

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync, sed

I'm trying to change the output position of a file transfer made with rsync, as shown below:

```
rsync -zvh --progress ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso /home/lnxusr/Downloads/
```

From this:

```
ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
        144.67M   5%   34.50MB/s    0:01:05
```

To this:

```
ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
144.67M   5%   34.50MB/s    0:01:05
```

However, when I pipe it to `| sed -u 's/[^\s]+//'`, I only get the static output which is:

```
ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I tried the answer suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200235/how-to-use-sed-to-manipulate-continuously-streaming-output) to turn off the buffering process with `stdbuf -o0` but got the same result as before.

Anyone knows this kind of output manipulation? or if is it even possible to position this output?

Comment: Why do you need leading spaces removed? Perhaps there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: AFAIK `[^\s]` is going to match anything that is not literal `\ ` or `s` and `+` is also literal unless you switch to extended regex mode (`-E` or `-r`). Try `sed -E 's/^\s+//'`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm trying to get a more precise positioning and design in a script output. @steeldriver `[^\s]` matches all leading spaces. I tested it with a simple file. No need for extended regex. I think that's more of a buffer problem, but have no idea if it has a turn around.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer might provide a better way:

- [How can I view a progress bar when running rsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609303/how-can-i-view-a-progress-bar-when-running-rsync)

rsync has a `--info` option that can be used to not only output the current progress, but also the transfer rate and elapsed time:

```
--info=FLAGS            fine-grained informational verbosity
```

The explanation of how to use it comes under the `-P` option in the man page:

```
-P     The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.  Its purpose is to
       make it much easier to specify these two options for a long transfer that
       may be interrupted.

       There is also a --info=progress2 option that outputs statistics based on
       the whole transfer, rather than individual files.  Use this flag
       without  out‐putting  a  filename  (e.g. avoid -v or specify --info=name0)
       if you want to see how the transfer is doing without scrolling the screen 
       with  a  lot  of names.   (You  don’t  need  to specify the --progress
       option in order to use --info=progress2.)
```

So trying using:

```
rsync -zvh --info=progress2 --info=name0 ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso /home/lnxusr/Downloads/
```

**Notes:**

- This gives the progress of the entire transfer, not for individual filenames.
- I do not have your source file nor target directory to test on my system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't remove the leading spaces of the rsync progress output. Maybe there's no solution to this kind of manipulation.