# Run a command for all directories

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I have a lot of directories that contain some text files and I would copy all files (of all directories) in a new directory. I'm looking for a bash command that do this. How can I do it?

Comment: No need to take care of name clashes? Is the target dir flat?

Comment: No, every directory has different file names

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find source_dir '*.txt' -exec cp -vuni '{}' dest_dir ";"
```

Comment: I don't understand the sintax, should `"dest_dir"`  be without inverted commas?

Comment: Without, but I think it does not matter (have only tried it without, though)

Comment: Please let me know if it worked ^^

Comment: The command worked in part. It copied all the files (.cc and executable included)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this command to copy all the files and subfolders in a directory to another directory:

```
cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

Taken from [How can I copy the contents of a folder to another folder in a different directory using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo)

Note:
This does not solve OP's question as you cannot use it to only copy files of a certain type along with folders, but I'll leave it here for anyone that might need it.

Comment: what about copy only .txt files? Have I to change the command like this : `cp -a /source/*.txt  /dest/` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'll run a quick test and get back to you in a couple mins.

Comment: I'm sorry but that isn't working. I guess the command I gave you will only work to copy ALL files and folders. Adding *.txt makes it no longer copy the directories. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I tried the command and didn't work. thank you anyway!