# Copy all files from one folder to another

Tags: command-line

I want to copy all the images from one folder to another. I have tried this
`!cp -r /content/COVID-19\ Radiography\ Database/COVID-19 /data`

but this creates a folder `COVID-19` in the `data` folder, and I don't want to create `COVID-19` folder in `data`, instead, I want to copy images directly.

**EDIT**
This command copying all files but in `COVID-19` folder which is in `data` folder. i want them directly in `data` folder

Comment: Try with this (check the first answer, that oen that says about folder 1 and folder 2) [https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo) PD: try to copy the final path(where would be the new folder) and past it in the console from the file explorer, maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a wildcard to grab everything in the folder.

`!cp -r /content/COVID-19\ Radiography\ Database/COVID-19/* /data`

The original command is interpreted as copy this folder (`COVID-19`) to folder `/data`. The wildcard will say to take all of the files in that folder and copy them to `/data`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

`-a` is for recursive copy
and `.` at the end is for copying the hidden files too.

Answer (score 0):

This code with **Flag "-R"** copies **perfectly all the contents** of **"folder1"** to existing **"folder2"**:

```js
cp -R folder1/. folder2
```

**Flag "-R"** copies **symbolic links** as well but **Flag "-r"** skips **symbolic links** so **Flag "-R"** is better than **Flag "-r"**.

- **The latest GNU Grep 3.7**:

```
-R, --dereference-recursive

For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, 
recursively, following all symbolic links.
```

```
-r, --recursive

For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, 
recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command line, but skip symlinks 
that are encountered recursively. Note that if no file operand is given, 
grep searches the working directory. This is the same as the 
‘--directories=recurse’ option.
```