# Copy all from a folder into the project root directory

Tags: command-line, cp

I have a web project with the following structure:

```
application/
dumps/
nginx/
logs/
.git/
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
README.md
.gitignore
```

For several reasons, I would like to dissolve the application folder and copy all files to the root directory. I would like to do this as usual via the CLI. However, I am not getting anywhere at the moment.

I have tried the following. I am in the root of the project.

```
cp -r application/ ./
// output cp: 'application/' and './application' are the same file

cp -r app/*.* ./
// copy only the root files from application to the project root and not the folders.
```

Which is kind of logical. How do I formulate the command so that it only copies the files to the root? *It's probably just a small thing but it's too early for me.*

Comment: @NateT I would remove applcaition but i will copie before removing all the contents to the root. Yes.

Comment: Remember that most files don't have extensions on Linux systems so the `*.*` is almost never what you want since that will only match files or directories that have a `.` in their name. To match everything, you just want `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. It was really to early ;-) The right command would be:

`cp -a app/. ./`

And better to use -a option instead of -r option.  It is an improved recursive option and means, that preserve all file attributes, and also preserve symlinks. Found it: [How can I copy the contents of a folder to another folder in a different directory using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo)

> The . at end of the source path is a specific cp syntax that allow to
> copy all files and folders, included hidden ones.

Comment: think you meant to do `cp -T app/ .` (probably wise to append `-i`)

Comment: @bac0n Thanks for comment. Why you advice to append the `i` option? and what means -T? i have copied it as in my answer and it has worked well "so far". should i be worried now?

Comment: @bac0n i means interactive. yes it would be good. thanks. but i dont found a explanation for the  -T option.

Comment: The target doesn't have to exist before copying is probably the main difference, next if *source* is a file and target a directory you get an error instead of the file being copied into the directory (should be cp -aT or -rT for recursive).

Comment: @Maik It's Bash, there are 10 separate ways to do anything. I was just working on a script yest. that uses both `cp -a` and a redirect from find within about 10-15 lines of each other. I would recommend looking further into all versions and learning the quirks and caveats of each. For example a set of commands may be exactly alike w/ params, but only one reads from stdin w/ none. This may not matter 90% of the time, but on that 10th time, it pays to know the diff. Figured I would point that out as it is what I was originally aiming at but I think I missed the mark before.

Comment: Note that this will also copy subdirectories, while your question is asking about files only. Not sure if this is intended or not.

Comment: @terdon files and folders. i will updated the title from my question.

Answer (score -1):

You just need a wildcard at the end of the command like so:

```
cp -r application/* ./
```

Comment: Thank you for answearing. But it doesnt work. `cp: missing destination file operand after 'sub/*'`

Comment: Yes that would work too. But i used `cp -a app/. ./` before and it works perfectly. I was unsettled by bac0n's comment. Do you happen to know what the `-T` option means?

Comment: Glad you got it. @MaikLowrey

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @MaikLowrey the original answer had quotes around the `"application/*"` which cause the glob (wildcard) not to be expanded. I fixed that, but the second command is completely wrong, I'm afraid. I _think_ what Nate meant was something like `find ./application/ -type f -exec cp {} ./ +`. The command in this answer will instead look for _directories_ in the directory `/application/` and then will append the list of directory names to a file called `/` which will fail since `/` is a directory.

Comment: Thank @terdon! You are right. I took `cp -a app/. ./` It is best to use the command with the -i option (thank to bac0n) to avoid overwriting files with the same name. In my case, "only" the .gitigniore was overwritten. Commands with recursion should be used carefully.